# Structure of $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combinations over an Abelian group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be an abelian group. I wonder if there is any algebraic structure over the $\mathbb{Z}$ terms that one can form over $G,$ in two variables $x$ and $y$ this will be the set of elements $nx+ my+ b$ where $n, m$ are integers and $b$ is an element in $G.$ Is this some sort of algebraic structure ?

Comment: Could you explain the motivation for this? It's not clear what sort of structure you are looking for, but with an example of what you are looking to generalize, it might be clearer.

Comment: I figured out what I needed thanks for your help!